# Adding Google maps API marker to map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented a marker to my map fragment but when I run the app on a device the map fragment shows up grey.It should show a marker and a geo location.My question is could this be a problem with the version of the api not being supported or a problem with the debug key.Also could there be a problem with the code implementation?

```
 public class MapGmit extends FragmentActivity implements OnGestureListener 
 {    

    private static final int MAJOR_MOVE = 0;
        //MapView map;
        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_gmit);
            /*map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
            map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);*/

            //code to add a map marker at GMIT geographic location
            GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(53.271900177, -9.04889965057))
                    .title("GMIT Galway Location"));;
        }
}
```

Comment: Inspect you LogCat, sounds as if there is a problem with your Maps API key. Btw you tagged it Maps API 3, did you not mean V2 as that is for android?

Comment: Please provide us more info like if this is the v2 version for Android, if you created the API Key correctly, your manifest, ...

Comment: The API version is Google 3.2.5 according to the manifest.I'm  guessing it's just a problem with the debug key.I don't have a device to test for the moment but will take your advice on board.Thanks

Comment: r u getting the map view?

Comment: See this [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/) may be helpful to you.